# How to customize std::make_heap comparison function based on some data structure?

Tags: c++, heap, stdvector

I am trying to use std::make_heap which has most of the properties I need.
I have a vector of ints which are just the indices of my data structure and I want the heap to be built upon some property of that data structure.
If I want to have a lambda function for comparison it would be simple:

```
[](int x, int y){return elementList[x]->lnc > elementList[y]->lnc;}
```

The problem I am facing is the comparison function just take 2 inputs and I cannot pass `elementList` to it.
I have two solutions in my mind. First, to store the pointers in the vector I have. Second is to implement the heap from scratch myself.
Is there a simpler solution?

Update: The capture clause in lambda function (Brian mentioned) is a good way . Is there any solution if I don't want to use the lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) takes three arguments: two iterators denoting a random access range, and a comparison function. Simply provide your custom comparison function are the third argument.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<Foo> v{/* ... */};

std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), [&elementList](auto lhs, auto rhs){ 
    return elementList[lhs]->lnc > elementList[rhs]->lnc;
});
```

Comment: It is the first thing I did. I know that make_heap has 3 input arguments, however your lambda  function has just two input arguments and there is no access to elementList inside. 
it is the error: error: ‘elementList’ is not captured

Comment: I can see that you pass elementList inside the brackets.